# Do classes with explicit constructors require piecewise_construct in emplace?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

If I create a struct with an `explicit` constructor

```
struct A {
    int x;
    explicit A(int x):x(x){};
};
```

And then use it as the `mapped_type` in a `std::map`, I am able to emplace with the piecewise constructor:

```
#include <map>
std::map<int, A> foo;

foo.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct, 
    std::forward_as_tuple(1), 
    std::forward_as_tuple(10)
    );
```

But I when I try to use the move or template constructors, I get errors and can't compile:

```
foo.emplace(std::make_pair(2, 20)); // <-- doesn't work
foo.emplace(3, 30);                 // <-- doesn't work
```

What's going on here? Until now, I hadn't appreciated that there was much of a difference between these different usages. I guess, with the pair move constructor, it could make sense that there's an implicit conversion from `std::pair<int, A>`... but why does that have to happen in the template constructor? And then why *not* with the piecewise constructor??

I've poked around a bit, but the docs for `std::map::emplace` and for `explicit` don't really clarify this for me.

Comment: Compiler/version?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before [N4387](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html), `pair<T1, T2>`'s constructors taking `U`/`V` [do not exist](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/pairs.pair#9) unless `U` is implicitly convertible to `T1` and `V` is implicitly convertible to `T2`:

> ```
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `is_constructible<first_type, U&&>::value` is `true` and `is_constructible<second_type, V&&>::value` is `true`.
>
> *Effects:* The constructor initializes `first` with `std::forward<U>(x)` and `second` with `std::forward<V>(y)`.
>
> *Remarks:* If `U` is not implicitly convertible to `first_type` or `V` is not implicitly convertible to `second_type` this constructor shall
>   not participate in overload resolution.

Likewise for the `const pair<U, V>&` and `pair<U, V>&&` constructor.

Since those constructors effectively don't exist, your later two `emplace`s will not work.

---

N4387 changed the rules here so that instead those constructors become `explicit` if both types are constructible from the corresponding argument type but at least one is not implicitly convertible from the argument type. In C++17, therefore, all three `emplace`s will compile. Also, as the paper [addresses a defect report raising pretty much this exact issue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2397) (among several), implementations may also choose to implement it in earlier standard modes.